# Analyze web service performance: simultaneous 32 and 64 bit targets

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-analysis

I am trying to analyze the performance of a web service project, by running it through WcfTestClient.exe. I have both that exe and the web service project set as targets in a performance analysis session. The exe is set as launch, but not to collect samples. The project is set to collect samples, but not as launch.

Unfortunately, when I try to start the session, I get an error that reads "Profiling 64-bit processes is not supported by this version of the profiling tools. Please use the profiling tools from the x64 directory." What I assume is happening is that the session starts by starting up WcfTestClient.exe, which is a 32 bit application. Because of that, it starts up the 32 bit version of the profiling tools. But my web service project is 64 bit, so when it reaches that point it throws that error since the 32 bit tools can't profile it.

Is there some way to force the session to use the 64 bit tools? Or perhaps there's a 64 bit version of the wcf test client?

Also before anybody calls me on this: I posted about this on the MSDN forums, and got a fairly useless non-answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsprofiler/thread/ff54e1fc-b9fb-47d4-9e9f-a3c552a6f242